# ESPN Now API and Sports API use different version of League

Tags: espn

Any reason why ESPN Now API and Sports API work a little differently?

**Now API:**

mma = League

ufc = Team
[image]

**Sports API:**

mma = Sport

ufc = League
[image]

*For example, as you can see "mma" saves as "Sport" in one and "League" in the other.*

Just wondering because I'm trying to **make the two work in concert** if Favorites are saved?

Let me know if you have any questions, thanks!

EDIT:
Just so everyone knows, as of December 7, the ESPN API is closed to the public.

Comment: @RogerRaymond any update on this being resolved finally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess and then probably open up a ticket for this.  The NOW API was built before we had MMA support in our core API offerings.  After working with our MMA data, we standardized on the format in our core sports API.

I'll add a ticket for this issue so we can get it resolved.  I'll try to reply here when that has been completed.  Also, we're looking into other methods of messaging out our routine changes to the API.

Regards,
Roger

Comment: Roger, thanks so much for opening up a ticket for it, thats a big help!  If you can reply here when its been completed, then yes that would be really great!

Comment: Any update on this Roger?  Just wanted to check in on it to see if it got resolved.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Just checking to see if this issue got resolved yet on the API.  I'm really chomping at the bit to integrate this part obviously :), so just wanted to check in on it hoping its done.  Just let me know, I appreciate it!

Comment: Any status on what the final change will be on this for resolution?  Thanks!

Comment: @rogerraymond can you help out with this, I'm having the same problem.  Or is the ticket resolved?